# Visualize multiple string segments

Tags: strings, underline

I need to compactly visualize multiple, possibly intersecting string segments for a given string. For instance, here is pseudocode for all palindrome occurrences in a binary string:

```
S = 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
    ----- --------- 
    - ----------- - 
      ----- -----   
      - ------- --- 
        - --- - -   
          - -
```

I want to render this in LaTeX in a compact way, preferrably with a readable LaTeX code.

My best attempt was using underlines, but it can only cover non-intersecting segments, imposes certain vertical order and is not particularly readable in code:

```latex
\begin{align*}
  \let\u\underline
  S = \u{\u{1}\,\u{0}\,\u{1}}\,\u{\u{\u{0}\,\u{0}}\,\u{1}\,\u{\u{0}\,\u{0}}}
\end{align*}
```

[image: Non-intersecting palindromes of S.]

Is there a way to visualize intersecting segments using underscores or other techniques? And if so, can I use nice code layout (as shown above or similar)?

**EDIT:** an extra challenge is to also enable visualisation of an empty substring between two consecutive symbols. For instance, here are palindromes ending/starting at index 4 in `S`, including an empty string (which is a degenerate palindrome):

```
S = 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 
           -
          - -
      ----- -----
```

Note that this can also be done by breaking the string, but it is usually undesired:

```
S = 1 0 1 0 _ 0 1 0 0
          -   -
      -----   -----
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax of the proposed command is

```
\segments[<width>]{<string>}{<segments>;<segments>;...}
```

where `<width>` is the width of the cells (default 1em), `<string>` is the string to typeset and `<segments>` is a list of cells to underline. Such a list consists of single numbers or `<number>-<number>` to mean the cells to straddle.

Note that this ignores spaces in both arguments (but ranges should be typed in without spaces), so the example can also be typed in like

```
\segments{1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0}{
  1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 ;
  1-3, 4-5, 7-8 ;
  4-8
}
```

if preferred.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,array,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\segments}{O{1em}mm}
 {% #1 = width of cells, #2 = string, #3 = list of underlines
  \group_begin:
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
  \fizruk_segments:n { #3 }
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} *{ \tl_count:n { #2 } }{ w{c}{#1} @{} } }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fizruk_string_seq { } { #2 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__fizruk_string_seq { & } \\
  \tl_use:N \l__fizruk_segments_tl
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
 }

\seq_new:N \l__fizruk_string_seq
\seq_new:N \l__fizruk_stages_seq
\tl_new:N \l__fizruk_segments_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fizruk_segments:n
 {
  \tl_clear:N \l__fizruk_segments_tl
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fizruk_stages_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__fizruk_stages_seq \__fizruk_segment_row:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__fizruk_segment_row:n
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__fizruk_add_segment:n
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__fizruk_segments_tl { \morecmidrules }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__fizruk_add_segment:n
 {
  \str_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { - }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__fizruk_segments_tl { \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){#1} }
   }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__fizruk_segments_tl { \cmidrule(l{2pt}r{2pt}){#1-#1} }
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
S=\segments{10100100}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8;1-3,4-5,7-8; 4-8}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here's the output of

```latex
\[
S=\segments{10100100}{
    1-3,4-8;
    1,2-7,8;
    2-4,5-7;
    2,3-6,7-8;
    3,4-5,6,7;
    4,5
  }
\]
```

[image]

With the following modification, you can insert a line between two symbols, denote it by `.3` if you want it to follow the third symbol.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,array,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\segments}{O{1em}mm}
 {% #1 = width of cells, #2 = string, #3 = list of underlines
  \group_begin:
  \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{0}
  \dim_set:Nn \l__fizruk_cell_dim { #1 }
  \fizruk_segments:n { #3 }
  \tl_show:N \l__fizruk_segments_tl
  \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} *{ \tl_count:n { #2 } }{ w{c}{#1} @{} } }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fizruk_string_seq { } { #2 }
  \seq_use:Nn \l__fizruk_string_seq { & } \\
  \tl_use:N \l__fizruk_segments_tl
  \end{tabular}
  \group_end:
 }

\dim_new:N \l__fizruk_cell_dim
\seq_new:N \l__fizruk_string_seq
\seq_new:N \l__fizruk_stages_seq
\tl_new:N \l__fizruk_segments_tl

\cs_new_protected:Nn \fizruk_segments:n
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__fizruk_segments_tl { \addlinespace[3pt] }
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fizruk_stages_seq { ; } { #1 }
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__fizruk_stages_seq \__fizruk_segment_row:n
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__fizruk_segment_row:n
 {
  \clist_map_function:nN { #1 } \__fizruk_add_segment:n
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__fizruk_segments_tl { \morecmidrules }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__fizruk_add_segment:n
 {
  \str_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { - }
   {
    \tl_put_right:Nx \l__fizruk_segments_tl { \__fizruk_cmidrule:nn { /5 } { #1 } }
   }
   {
    \str_if_in:nnTF { #1 } { . }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__fizruk_segments_tl
       {
        \__fizruk_cmidrule:ne { *4/5 } { \tl_tail:n { #1 }-\int_eval:n { \tl_tail:n { #1 }+1 } }
       }
     }
     {
      \tl_put_right:Nx \l__fizruk_segments_tl { \__fizruk_cmidrule:nn { /5 } { #1-#1 } }
     }
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__fizruk_cmidrule:nn
 {
  \exp_not:N\cmidrule(l{\dim_eval:n{\l__fizruk_cell_dim #1}}r{\dim_eval:n{\l__fizruk_cell_dim #1}}){#2}
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__fizruk_cmidrule:nn { ne }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\[
S=\segments{10100100}{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8;1-3,4-5,7-8; 4-8}
\]

\[
S=\segments{10100100}{
    1-3,4-8;
    1,2-7,8;
    2-4,5-7;
    2,3-6,7-8;
    3,4-5,6,7;
    4,5
  }
\]

\[
S = \segments{1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0}{
      .3;
      3,4;
      2-4,5-7
    }
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The apparent disparity in the thickness of the lines is due to the conversion to PNG.

Comment: Looks nice, thanks! Would it also be possible to mark a segment in between letters? That is having a separate underline between two consecutive letters. Sometimes I need to emphasize empty substrings that I build up on. I guess I can do that manually with a simple underline, but I wondered if `segments` command allows for that.

Comment: @fizruk You mean something like `\segments{1 1 \_ 0 0}{...}`?

Comment: this would be one solution, yes! But I was more interested in a way that does not change/break original string. I have edited question to include an example of what I have in mind.

Comment: @fizruk Added as requested

Comment: Would you know why I am getting an error `Variant form 'ne' invalid for base form '\__fizruk_cmidrule:nn'.` trying this code with in an ACM conference paper template?

Comment: @fizruk You should update your TeX system.

Answer (score 4):

I just did three rows here but

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}

\[
  \begin{array}{r@{}*{10}{c}}
    S={}&1&0&1&0&0&1&0&0 \\
\cmidrule(r){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-9}
\morecmidrules
\cmidrule(r){2-2}\cmidrule(lr){3-8}\cmidrule(l){9-9}
\morecmidrules
\cmidrule(r){3-5}\cmidrule(l){6-7}
  \end{array}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Seems a straight copy from my answer…

Comment: @egreg all my answers are straight copies of yours (even if I write them before you have posted them)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thank you! Can you elaborate what `l`, `r` and `lr` mean in `cmidrule`? What should I do if I have more that 3 segments in a single layer?

Comment: @fizruk it means trim the line from the right or left or both, if you do neither they run together with no gaps, actually it may look better to use `rl` on them all, but I didn't trim the outside edges here, see which you prefer, you can have as many cmidrule in a row as you need. (use `(lr)` for all the middle ones.

Answer (score 3):

A solution using ti*k*Z. The notation goes as follows:
in `\ourInfo` array, each cell corresponds to: *{level, starting character index (including), finish character index(including)}*

[image: Output]

```
\documentclass[margin=1cm, tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    \def\binaryString{{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0}}
    %Notation: {level, starting character index (including), finish character index(including)}
    %NOTE! Everyting is zero-based
    \def\ourInfo{{
        % Level 0
        {0,0,2},{0,3,7},
        % Level 1
        {1,0,0},{1,1,6},{1,7,7},
        % Level 2
        {2,1,3},{2,4,7},
        % Level 3
        {3,1,1},{3,2,5},{3,6,7},
        % Level 4
        {4,2,2},{4,3,4},{4,5,5},{4,6,6},
        % Level 5
        {5,3,3},{5,4,4}
    }}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\length}{15}% Zero based.
    \foreach \i in {0, ..., 7}{
        \draw[] (\i,0) node{\pgfmathparse{\binaryString[\i]}\pgfmathresult};
    }
    \foreach \i in {0, ..., \length}{
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\level}{\ourInfo[\i][0]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\start}{\ourInfo[\i][1]}
        \pgfmathsetmacro{\finish}{\ourInfo[\i][2]}
        \draw[thick] (\start-0.3,-0.5-\level/2)--(\finish+0.3,-0.5-\level/2){};
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! I guess I could omit level and use `\i` in the last loop. Would it also be possible to mark a segment in between letters? That is having a separate underline between two consecutive letters. Sometimes I need to emphasize empty substrings that I build up on. Could this be as simple as `{0, 0.5, 0.5}` to place a segment between first and second symbols in a string?